# good rating control?

Tags: asp.net

I was looking for a good rating control [1/2 star] like 0,0.5, 1, 1.5 etc.

I need to get the user rating and need to set the same rating on a different page by using same control.

I am using asp.net 3.5 + ajax, so please help me get a good half star rating control.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For that you should first take half star image in image folder. then according to  tag value in rating property you can assign rating.

Answer (score 0):

Try **[fyneworks](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/)**

**[Google codes Jquery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-star-rating-plugin/)**

I have implemented the latter in one clients requirement, its easy to implement =]

Answer (score 0):

There's a (server) [Rating control in the Ajax Control Tookit](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Rating/Rating.aspx):

> "The Rating control provides an
>   intuitive rating experience that
>   allows users to select the number of
>   stars that represents their rating.
>   The page designer can specify the
>   initial rating, the maximum rating to
>   allow, the alignment and direction of
>   the stars, and custom styles for the
>   different states a star can have.
>   Rating also supports a ClientCallBack
>   event that allows custom code to run
>   after the user has rated something."

Comment: I am not sure if it allow half star rating. Please clarify.

Comment: I don't think it does half stars, but you can change the number of stars it uses. So 10 stars gives the same granularity as 5 half stars.

Comment: I already used that, by having 10 stars, but you know, sometimes client's just don't understand. LOL. :)

Anyway, please tell me if there is some other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

[Unobtrusive AJAX Star Rating Bar](http://masugadesign.com/the-lab/scripts/unobtrusive-ajax-star-rating-bar/) supports half rating stars, but is no longer supported

[image]
<sub>(source: [masugadesign.com](http://masugadesign.com/images/uploads/rating-sample.gif))</sub>